# Django for...empty with different container when empty

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a common pattern in which I have a container in HTML (e.g., ul, table ...) with elements from a queryset. However, when the list is empty, I don't want to display the container itself.

I seek to get the equivalent of

```
{% if query.exists %}
  <ul class="list-of-stuff">
    {% for x in query %}
      <li>{{ x }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  <p class="information">
    The list is empty.
  </p>
{% endif %}
```

but without extra query (`query.exists`), much like `for...empty` does. However, one large drawback of `for...empty` is that I cannot remove or change the container when the list is empty.

How can I get an equivalent of the above with only one execution of my query in a clean way (i.e., without displaying the container tag `if forloop.first` and such)? I'm open for implementing new tags or filters or using a lightweight library with these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the truthiness of the `query` itself, this will load the data into memory, so then it is only a *single* query. We thus check `{% if query %}`, not `{% if query.exists %}`:

```
{% if query %}
  <ul class="list-of-stuff">
    {% for x in query %}
      <li>{{ x }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  <p class="information">
    The list is empty.
  </p>
{% endif %}
```

Indeed, a `QuerySet` has truthiness `True` if it contains *at least one element*. It will thus make the query, and load the data into memory. If there are no records, then the `{% if query %}` fails, and thus we render that the list is empty. In case there is at least one row, then `{% if query %}` succeeds, and then we do not have to make an extra query to enumerate over the `query`.